# How to use for loop for varying ul & li both?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

It may be already asked question,but I am unable to find it.
Below is the code I am using:

```
List<WebElement> allElementswithLetter = Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'page-bg clearfix search-locality')]/ul[i]/li"));
```

here *ul* is varying in every iteration in for loop, but my script is unable to identify it.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate the question a little bit please?

Comment: ul[1]/li has some webelements,ul[2]/li has and so on.so i am trying to put a for loop on ul[i]  and putting the all corresponding li's  in webelement and performing operations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your xpath "`ul[i]`" will try to find `<ul>` element having child element `<i>`. Instead of that, I believe you want the value of variable named `i` to be concatenated into your xpath.

You could try to achieve the latter via string concatenation like so :

```
String xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'page-bg clearfix search-locality')]/ul[" + i + "]/li"
List<WebElement> allElementswithLetter = Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a nested loop like the following then. First find the `ul` and then find the `li` under `ul`

```
List<WebElement> uls = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'page-bg clearfix search-locality')]/ul[" + i + "]"));
for (WebElement element: uls){
   List<WebElement> lis = element.findElements(By.xpath("//li"));
   for (int j=0;j<lis.size();j++){
      //do some operation
   }
}
```